Cross-Origin Request Blocked how do I fix it?
guys. I encountered an error while trying to use the signup form of my site it gives me this error Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at in the console of the browser.
I've read it's about the fact that I use my PC as both server for the site itself and database where I want to store the user data, but I don't know how to fix it. For database I use MongoDB if that's something that is important. I'm not sure where the problem is so I will post the whole project from github. https://github.com/borki6a/Dreamsurvey

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy and then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS.

You need something like


app.use(require("cors")({
        origin: 'http://my-frontend-url-here',
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200
}));



in your server.js
